# Applying a t-test over multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I would like to apply a t-test to a data frames with differing column lengths.

I have to two data frames:

DF1:

| Group | Name | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Max | 435 |
| B | Jake | 657 |
| A | Sarah | 99 |

DF2:

| Group | Name | Weight | bmi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mat | 435 | 16 |
| B | Amy | 657 | 35 |
| A | John | 99 | 25 |

In reality my data frames are much longer and differ by about 100 columns, but have the same organization.

I want to look at the differences in each column by Group. For example, I want to apply a t-test comparing the weights of Group A to the weights of Group B from DF1.

When presented with DF2, I want the t.test to compare the weights between groups A and B AND also compare the bmi between groups A and B.

This is what I have so far:

```
lapply(DF2[-2], function(x) t.test(x ~ DF2$Group))
```

I get this error:

Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In var(y) :
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Is there a way to avoid specifying exact column names, but instead telling the t.test function to apply the stats test on every column after the second?

Comment: `lapply(names(DF2)[3:4], function(x) t.test(reformulate('Group', x), DF2))`

Comment: @Onyambu I want it to iterate over several columns after the second, not just the 3rd and 4th. I want to be able to feed it several data frames with varying numbers of columns after the second.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by [Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu), you could use

```r
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  name = paste0("name", 1:6), 
  weight = c(1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 2),
  bmmi = c(20, 14, 32, 55, 42, 12)
)
df
#>   group  name weight bmmi
#> 1     A name1      1   20
#> 2     A name2      4   14
#> 3     A name3      2   32
#> 4     B name4      3   55
#> 5     B name5      5   42
#> 6     B name6      2   12
variables <- names(df)[-c(1, 2)] # don't use first the two names
variables
#> [1] "weight" "bmmi"
ttests <- lapply(variables, function(x) t.test(reformulate("group", x), data = df))
ttests[[1]] # view the first
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  weight by group
#> t = -0.80178, df = 4, p-value = 0.4676
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group A and group B is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -4.462835  2.462835
#> sample estimates:
#> mean in group A mean in group B 
#>        2.333333        3.333333
```

The `variables` vector will contain all variable names in the data frame except the first two, and `lapply()` will iterate through each element in `variables`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop both the first two columns. Also the t.test requires at least two values for x and y. I cloned your DF2 dataframe in the following:

```
df2 = structure(list(Group = c("A", "B", "A"), Name = c("Mat", "Amy", 
"John"), Weight = c(435L, 657L, 99L), bmi = c(16L, 35L, 25L)), class =
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) 
df3 = rbind(df2, df2)
lapply(df3[c(-1,-2)], function(x) t.test(x ~ Group, data=df3))

#         Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  x by Group
# t = -4, df = 3, p-value = 0.03
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group A and group B is 
# not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -699  -81
# sample estimates:
# mean in group A mean in group B 
#             267             657 
# 
# 
# $bmi
# 
#         Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  x by Group
# t = -6, df = 3, p-value = 0.01
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group A and group B is 
# not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -22.8  -6.2
# sample estimates:
# mean in group A mean in group B 
#              20              35
```

Comment: To be more responsive to OP, edited to indicate dropping first two columns of df3 dataframe rather than selecting columns 3 and 4.